# Javascript RegExp to match user ID pattern

Tags: javascript

I am using C# code below to detect if a string is formatted E123456, H123456 or T123456.

```
Regex(@"\b[eht]\d{6}")
```

I am trying to use the Javascript equivalent but am having difficulties.

So far I have, but it's returning false each time when it should be returning true.

```
RegExp("\b[eht]\d{6}")
```

Any help will be appreciated, or a good link to RegExp formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue you are having is due to the fact that when using the RegExp constructor with a string argument, special characters such as slashes and quotation marks must be escaped with the backslash character. Also, use the `i` flag if you want to allow both upper and lower case matches.

To make the RegExp with the constructor method, you would use:

```
new RegExp("\\b[eht]\\d{6}", "i")
```

Or to make a RegExp literal, go with:

```
var regExName = /\b[eht]\d{6}/i
```

Also, if you want to experiment more with RegEx's in JavaScript, http://regexr.com/ is a wonderful site that I highly recommend!

Comment: Tamas's solution worked and so did yours.  But I voted for your answer because you also provided me with some additional resources to check out.  I appreciate it very much. TY.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex only matches lower case characters while your user ids have upper case E, H and T. So either use upper case in the regex string (`RegExp("\b[EHT]\d{6}")`) or use the `i` flag (`RegExp("\b[eht]\d{6}",'i')`)

- Reference for the flags: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
- Online tester for the upper case solution: https://regex101.com/r/yW9zF2/1
- Online tester for the flag solution: https://regex101.com/r/mZ1vX9/1

Answer (score 0):

There is some trouble with escaping the string, and as I see the regex should be case insensitive. Try this regex expression:

```
/\b[eht]\d{6}/i
```

Or using the `RegExp` constructor:

```
new RegExp("\\b[eht]\\d{6}", "i")
```